# Prediction for horse racing scikit learn - multiple rows per race

Tags: python, scikit-learn

#### Goal

I want to train a model with Scikit-learn that predicts the outcome of horse races. I have a **CSV file that includes multiple features like position, age, weight, horse_name, race_id etc.**

#### Problem

In my original CSV file each horse is represented in one row. With positions from 1-8 each race consists of 8 rows. When I train my model however, the **model looks at each row as an individual event (race)** and therefore does not perform well.

#### Approach

I tried to solve this issue and created a new CSV file in which each row represents one race and the features go from position1, age1, weight1, horse_name1, race_id1 to position8, age8, weight8, horse_name8, race_id8 **(see below)**. However, using a Multioutput in this case my model does not train at all but notices that age1, weight1 are the columns of the winner and does get 100 percent accuracy.

#### Ideas

I wonder if there is a way to solve this issue. Maybe it is possible to use the original file but somehow **tell the model that the rows with the same race_id have to be treated as one event**. I could think of using groupby(race_id) but I was not able to feed the new groups into the model. Also you might use a bag for each race like when doing predictions for text data.

I am actually stuck here so any suggestions are much appreciated :)

```
ORIGINAL DF 

position horse age weight race_id 

1        name1 3y  900    1 
2        name2 4y  800    1
3        name3 5y  760    1
...      ...   ... ...    ...
8        name8 7y  980    1
1        name9 4y  880    2
...      ...   ... ...    ...
8       name16 5y  770    2

NEW DF 

position1 horse1 weight1 race_id1 ... position8 horse8 weight8 race_id8 

1         name1  900     1            8         name8  980     1 
1         name9  880     2            8         name16 770     2
```

Comment: I'd like to know if the `horse` column at `ORIGINAL DF` is unique. Could you share a small part of your dataset for us to help you?

Comment: since u mention accuracy, are u treating this as classification? wouldn't it be better treated as regression (or ranking)? also, I have a feeling independent treatment of each row is not a big problem if you post process regression result to transform them into 1-8 positions

Comment: @ShihabShahriarKhan you are right I am treating it as a classification for the positions. I agree with you that it might be also a good idea to treat it as a regression, predict the finish time and order them from 1-8. However, I think that the predictions are more accurate if the model looks at each race as one event. For example if one horse has a very good finishing time the others might be better as well because the other horses are rushing too.

Comment: @HenriqueBranco the horse column is in that way unique that the "name1", "name2" is for that individual horse. The same horse however might appear multiple times in the data as it appears in multiple races
I do not have one particular dataset yet, but looking at the available datasets they were all structured the same and I could not overcome my problem

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you figure it out? if so could you post or link to the solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if I correctly understand your problem you want to convert your old dataframe to new dataframe and feed that to your model.
 you can use this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
df = pd.DataFrame({'position': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'horse': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name8'],
                   'age': ['4y', '4y', '5y', '7y'],
                   'weight': [800, 978, 76, 565],
                   'race_id': [1, 1, 2, 2]})

groupby_race = df.groupby(['race_id'])
arr = []
for name, group in groupby_race:
    r = np.concatenate([row.values for index, row in group.iterrows()])
    arr.append(r)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data=arr, columns = ['position1', 'horse1', 'age1', 'weight1', 'race_id1',
                                           'position2', 'horse2', 'age2', 'weight2', 'race_id2'])
```

Comment: No I already have that new df. My question is more about the understanding of Machine Learning and how I could use either my old or new df to make a good prediction.

To create the new df I used this simple code: 
s=df.assign(key=df.groupby('race_id').cumcount()+1).set_index(['race_id','key']).stack().unstack([1,2])
s.columns=s.columns.map('{0[1]}{0[0]}'.format)

Comment: your approach is very elegant by the way! Felix are you working on a particular dataset?  could you share that ?

Comment: if your target is finish time I think the problem is much easier to solve and you can treat each row independently I think, take a look at this paper:
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0191/19dff662e50678563bb50bccca13d433bab2.pdf?_ga=2.143262577.596549207.1587647628-204272250.1587647628

Comment: I am not using a particular dataset but for all datasets that are available the problem is the same. 
You might be right that it could be easier or better to predict the finish time. However, I think it still makes a difference if each row is treated individually. Other horses might be racing faster due to the competitiveness one fast horse has on them. For example one horse with "the best features" might improve the finish time of the other ones in the prediction if it is treated as one race.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is doable here is to create a logistic regression using the sklearn library which allows us to predict the chances of winning for each horse. I imagine it to be quite difficult to incorporate the fact of who the horse is racing against in each run. So here is what I would do:

1. Assign a column to your data frame for whether the horse won or not
2. Split into train and test data
3. Implement sklearn.LogisticRegression
4. Fit LogisticRegression
5. Report score

It might be advisable to check what features of your dataset are important so a principal component analysis would be helpful to reduce the dimension of your predictor space. In addition, the logistic regression assumes that our predictors are independent of each other and so you might need to do some exploratory analysis first to see whether there is some collinearity in your dataset.

Documentation for the Logistic Regression: (https://scikitlearn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)

Would love to try it out myself if you would want to share your dataset!